# Getting dependencies from jar(war/ear)?

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, gradle

Assuming I have a poor maintained project with all libs located in the CVS/Hard Drive and build running in pure Ant (without Ivy) or even compiled with IDE. Is there a tool that can look on the final product (jar/war/ear) and give me some report about it's dependencies, or even create a sample pom.xml/build.gradle?

Comment: I think this link might be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474725/generating-a-maven-pom-from-an-existing-project

Comment: Doesn't look so... In fact it people explained to me not that trivial task, because in Maven Central/Bintray there are lots of same jars under different groupID's. But it still looks resolvable to me.

Answer (score 0):

What could help is the [Advanced Search](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav) of Maven Central. With the 'By SHA-1 Checksum' you can select your jars. If that jar is available at Maven Central, you will get its coordinates.
This would be a good start and hopefully will resolve most of your dependencies.